# How can I format a datetime in SQL Server R2 to dd-MMM-yy (or dd-mon-yy)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, datetime-format

Sample input: `2014-03-28 00:00:00.000`

Sample output: `28-Mar-14`

Current SQL:

```
SELECT StartDate
FROM myTable
```

Surprisingly, I could not find this particular format on StackOverflow for SQL Server so I thought I should add it to help save the next person some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New SQL:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(9), StartDate, 6),' ','-') AS FormattedStartDate
FROM myTable
```

Here's how it works in case you need to adjust for your needs:

`CONVERT(CHAR(9), StartDate, 6)` will output a `CHAR(9)`. Make sure this is long enough for your desired output.

The value of `6` in the 3rd parameter tells `CONVERT` to output in the format 
`dd mon yy`.

Notice that format has spaces which is why you need the `REPLACE` function if you want hyphens (-), slashes (/), or whatever instead of those spaces.

NOTE: If the date field is usually not null, CHAR(9) will use fewer bytes than VARCHAR. If there are a lot of blank data in the field, I would consider replacing the CHAR(9) with a VARCHAR because it will output fewer bytes in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),6),' ','-')
```

Your query will be :-

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,StartDate,6),' ','-') AS StartDate FROM myTable
```

Comment: Why convert to a VARCHAR instead of a CHAR? Will the length of the output ever be anything other than 9?

Comment: @TonyL.: Does it matter? What advantage do you expect `CHAR` to have over `VARCHAR`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If the data is always the same length, CHAR would use 2 fewer bytes. I would assume that's better but judging by your profile, you would know better than I would so I'm certainly open to input.

Comment: @TonyL. -- true about the byte size (could be 8 or 9 right?) -- but if you're that concerned about sql-server processing a single wasted byte (x however many records), you might think instead about passing an even smaller (4-byte) smalldatetime to your business/presentation layer and doing the conversion there instead.  (Maybe you can even get your consumer's computer to do the work, instead of your server(s)).

Comment: @VanHalen Good Point. My inherited code just outputs whatever is in a certain view. Frankly, the performance probably won't be noticeable. My main concern is that if I'm going to put an answer on SO, which could be copy/pasted by many, I want to make sure the best answer is out there in case it does matter for someone else.

Comment: In this case, CHAR(9) will put out 9 bytes, of course, and VARCHAR will put out 11 bytes. However, if the field is null, then I would expect that VARCHAR would output 2 bytes. Thus, if there's a lot of nulls in the field, then I might lean toward this answer.

Comment: U can use char as well. Good if it serves u r purposel